# Editar cadastrado que contém imagem

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

Tenho meu model:

```
public class Produto 
{
   public int Id {get;set;}
   public string Nome {get;set;}
   public byte[] Imagem {get;set;}
}
```

Como eu trato se ele está "removendo" ou está Editando(Substituindo) a imagem do Produto?
Na minha View:

```
  @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ImagemUpload, new { type = "file", @class = "filestyle form-control", @data_size = "sm" })
```

No meu ViewModel tenho a propriedade

```
public HttpPostedFileBase ImagemUpload{ get; set; }
```

A qual verifico no controller

```
if(model.ImagemUpload!= null) 
{
   Tem Imagem então salva/Edita
}
```

Aqui no Editar, Novo, funciona, mas como sei quando ele está removendo? Pois se ele está removendo o model.ImagemUpload virá Null, e preciso deletar o valor que está com Byte[] em minha tabela.

Answer (score 1):

O que eu costumo fazer nesses caso é uma requisiçao Ajax separada no momento em que ele clica em remover a imagem.

Outra alternativa é assim que ele clicar em remover a imagem, voce apenas exclui ela da tela e adiciona um `<input type="hidden" name="imagem_excluida" value="true />` no HTML. Dessa forma, quando o formulario for submetido, voce checa essa propriedade para saber se houve ou nao uma exclusao.